# How to specify label titles & visibility for certain subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to make a pyramidal graph of all analytes of a sample graphed against one another. For example if I had some number of rows of a df which each had values for columns 'SiO2', 'TiO2', 'Al2O3', 'FeO', 'MgO', 'CaO','Na2O', 'K2O' then I would get a graph like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make this adaptable to any length of "columns" so that a user can change the values and still get a similar graph. My current code is sort of working in terms of the iteration and placement:

```
columns = ['SiO2', 'TiO2', 'Al2O3', 'FeO', 'MgO', 'CaO','Na2O', 'K2O']
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,8), squeeze=False)
for i in range (0, len(columns)-1):
    for j in range(0,len(columns)):
        if j > i:
            break
        else:
            ax = plt.subplot2grid((len(columns)-1,len(columns)-1), (i,j)).scatter(df[columns[j]], samples[columns[i+1]])
```

This gives me a plot like

[image]

However, now I need to figure out how to add titles to only the outside plots,  as well as remove the numbers/ticks from the inside plots. I think that perhaps I could solve the problem by naming each plot differently, but I'm not sure how to do that. If this was the case, then I could say which plots to hideaxis, and which plots to give an axis label. Looking for any ideas, thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started: when `j == 0` you're on the leftmost column, and when `i == len(columns) - 1` you're on the bottom row.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However that wasn't really my question, since the graphs are being plotted correctly. I'm just asking how to take off the ticks for specific plots, and to add axis labels to specific plots.

Comment: Remove ticks: `ax.set_xticks([])`. Add axis labels: `ax.set_xlabel("label")`. Combined with the comment above and by not naming the scatter `ax`, but the subplot itself, this should allow you to get the desired plot.